# How to disable auto update Google Play Store and Google Play Service

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-services

My phone broken WiFi (couldn't scan WiFi around). So, I have to use phone data. However, I'm having problems with two apps: Google Play Store and Google Play Services usually updating, consume a lot of phone memory, and use more and more network data (I pay a lot of money for them).

I have gone to "Settings" and chose "Disable auto update" but it just didn't update the other apps but it kept updating the two apps themselves.

So, I hope people can give me some solutions to solve this problem okay?

Comment: Having a similar issue with one of my devices, but my workaround is using a firewall application to disable internet access for these apps.

Comment: I agree with Xavier. This works as long as you don't open an app requiring Play Services, such as Maps, in which case you would have to permit internet access to Play Services as well to use the former app's full functionality and thus have to bear the burden of updates too.

Comment: See this answer
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/197499/when-turned-on-wi-fi-something-unknown-uses-data-suddenly/197579#197579